# How can i reset the Membership.ApplicationName

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i reset the Membership.ApplicationName

I have this configured in the Web.Config file

However in my code behind on the index page I had it set to

```
Membership.ApplicationName = "/test";
```

Now every time I try to log back in, the `Membership.ApplicationName` is already set to "/test" instead of what I've set in the Web.Config file.

How can I force this to pick up the `Membership.ApplicationName` value from WebConfig file rather than use the old one I've set.

I tried rebuilding the solution and its not working either.

Comment: You've removed that line from your code behind right?

Comment: its not set in the log in page... it was set on a page after log in is done.. but now everytime i start my application, its set to "/test" on the log in page as well.  Shouldn't it be picking up the value from my web.config file?